# How to create Custom Annotations in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a scenario in which I want to run two methods at the start of function and end of a function, like this:

```
void someFunction(){
  runA()
  //someFunctionLogic
  runB()
}
```

I can manually add `runA()` and `runB()` for a function. But is there any other way to do it, something like using annotations for an example

```
@doRun
void someFunction(){
  //someFunctionLogic
}
```

Which should exactly equal to the first one, it's like the use of `@lombok` in a way if you are familiar with Java, basically, my idea is without touch functions inside can we inject some functionalities to that?

Thank you.

Comment: Annotations in Dart are not like, say, decorators in Python.  Dart annotations don't *do* anything; they only provide hints to the static analyzer.

Comment: is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: No, at best you can create a helper function that takes your function logic as a callback , as described in the linked question/answer.

Comment: If anyone come here by I could do something similar to this  using `extensions`